# Lmodern: LaTeX tries to create tfm files for EC fonts

Tags: lmodern

Assume minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
A.
\end{document}
```

When *not* having texlive-fonts-recommended installed one notices that metafont tries to generate tfm files out of the EC fonts, which fails. Log files from the LaTeX run can be provided, but the error message is clear.

The lmodern fonts have their own set of tfm files. Therefore I'm wondering why the system tries to create metric files from another font set. Could you explain?

Comment: your question is not very clear but presumably you have not installed the lm tfm files, so the default behaviour for web2c before giving an error is to try calling metafont to make the files.

Comment: since most of use do have the fonts it would be helpful if you provided the log file as reproducing it is inconvenient

Comment: Sorry, for being unspecific!  
I'm using Debian unstable and I have the package lmodern installed, else there wouldn't be lmodern.sty. This package contains a lot of tfm files, see [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/lmodern/filelist).  
I'm just wondering, why LaTeX in additions tries to access the tfm files from the EC fonts. At least /usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/ec-lmr10.tfm is found and opened.  
Here is the missfont log. Do you really need the complete LaTeX log file?  
  
mktextfm ecrm1000
mktextfm ecrm1000

Comment: without a log I couldn't even guess answer.  ecrm1000 is the specified error font in T1 encoding so it will try that if everything else fails, but I can't say why you get there if you have the lm fonts installed. The log would give some clues.

Comment: Hello Hilmar, hope you're fine! The problem is due to `fontenc.sty` doing `\fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont` while `\f@family` hasn't been updated to reflect the change from `\usepackage{lmodern}`. If you modify `fontenc.sty` to add `\fontfamily{\familydefault}` before `\fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont`, the document compiles fine using only `lmodern` and none of the EC fonts. This implies that the behavior reported here is perfectly reproducible (I'm on Debian unstable too, but I don't think it matters—all you have to do to see it is to uninstall the EC fonts).

Comment: @HilmarPreuße Of course, keeping the official `fontenc.sty`, you can add `\fontfamily{\familydefault}\selectfont` or `\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\selectfont` or `\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont` after `\usepackage{lmodern}` in your document and this will fix the problem too.

Comment: @Florent. Hope you're fine too! Many thanks for your explanation, both solutions work for us. Do you see this as bug in fontenc.sty? Does it needs to be fixed?

Comment: Hilmar, you have to write `frougon` after the at sign, otherwise I'm not notified (I went back here “just in case”). I'm not sure one can say there is a `fontenc` bug here (I'm not a LaTeX maintainer!), but even if this were the case, adding `\fontfamily{\familydefault}` to `fontenc.sty` as I did to diagnose the problem would probably cause compatibility issues. @DavidCarlisle or someone really knowledgeable can probably comment better.

Comment: So, I would say that the document-level solutions seem to be appropriate here. However, I admit that the behavior you described is puzzling at first. For reference, there *is* an implicit switch to `\familydefault` (which activates `ec-lmr10` in your document when any of the possible fixes is applied) from `\begin{document}` in two steps: 1) `\document` calls `\process@table` which does `\fontfamily{\familydefault}`, then 2) `\document` uses `\normalsize` which does `\@setfontsize \normalsize \@xpt \@xiipt`, which executes `\fontsize{#2}{#3}\selectfont`.

Comment: @frougon Sorry, I wasn't aware of the E-Mail notification feature. Just set my one from Daily to 3hours.  
I had a short look at both LaTeX bug data bases, but did not find a trace, that this was ever reported and hence considered to be a (minor) bug. Great thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I uploaded the logfile here: https://paste.debian.net/1095272 . I guess the missfont.log is not of much interest. Thanks! Sorry for late response.